# Access child class instance in parent class constructor

Tags: c#

I have searched a lot around but didn't find solution to my problem.

I have created a base class `MyProjectBase` which inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class. This Base class is supposed to call some static functions of a static class `General`. For example, I have a function `CheckSecurity(Form frm)`. I need each of child class of `MyProjectBase` should call this `CheckSecurity()` function but with its own child class instance. Here is sample code:

```
public static class General {
    public static void CheckSecurity(System.Windows.Forms.Form frm) {
        // Does Security Check on frm
    }
}

public class MyProjectBase : System.Windows.Forms.Form {
    public MyProjectBase() {
        General.CheckSecurity(this);
    }
}

public class ChildA : MyProjectBase {
    // I need this class instance to call the General.CheckSecurity() function
    // but pass its own ChildA instance to that function automatically, without
    // even writing constructor of ChildA class
}
```

Is it possible? I can get the Type Name of `ChildA` class in Parent class using `GetType()`, but not the actual instance of `ChildA` class.

EDIT:
If there is any alternate approach for solving this problem, please tell me about that.

EDIT Solution:
Actually I wanted to access the controls of `ChildA` class, which is actually a `Form` object. I just modified the MyProjectBase class as follows: -

```
public class MyProjectBase : System.Windows.Forms.Form {
    public MyProjectBase() {
     InitializeComponent();   
    }
    private void MyProjectBase_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        General.CheckSecurity(this);
    }
}
```

And it worked. Earlier it was not working because `ChildA` object was not getting initialized...

Never the less. Thanks for help everyone. I get my problem solved.

Comment: what is the behavior currently ?

Comment: I have created instance of ChildA() class. It calls constructor of MyProjectBase class, and sends the instance of MyProjectBase class. I need instance of ChildA() class to be sent to that function.

Comment: you would need to add child class constructor, i don't think without that you can achieve that

Comment: Could you check in debug what is the type of `this` in the `MyProjectBase` constructor when you call `new ChildA()`? I would bet it is already of the `ChildA` type.

Comment: When I check `this`, I get this {ProjectName.ChildA, Text: MyProjectBase}

Comment: So this proves that `this` is of type `ProjectName.ChildA`. I bet somewhere in the `MyProjectBase` constructor (or in called methods such as `InitializeComponent`) there is a line `this.Text = "MyProjectBase"`.

Comment: Yes it is a windows form. Its text is same.

Answer (score 3):

Your current implementation should work exactly as you want.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        BaseClass bc = new BaseClass(); // outputs xxx.BaseClass
        BaseClass dc = new DerivedClass(); // outputs xxx.DerivedClass
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{GetType()}");
    }
}

public class DerivedClass: BaseClass
{
    // default constructor calls base constructor
    // and `this` object refers to DerivedClass instance
}
```

Or your particular code:

```
public static class General {
    public static void CheckSecurity(System.Windows.Forms.Form frm) {
        // Does Security Check on frm
        frm.GetType(); // check the type here
    }
}

public class MyProjectBase : System.Windows.Forms.Form {
    public MyProjectBase() {
        General.CheckSecurity(this);
    }
}

public class ChildA : MyProjectBase {
    /*
       You don't have to add your own constructor. By default
       MyProjectBase class constructor is called every time you create
       new instance of ChildA.

       And in MyProjectBase constructor you have `this` of the origin object, 
       so it has the right type `ChildA` for objects of type ChildA.
    */


    // I need this class instance to call the General.CheckSecurity() function
    // but pass its own ChildA instance to that function automatically, without
    // even writing constructor of ChildA class
}
```

Comment: Everytime I create instance of ChildA class, the name of object of MyProjectBase is passed to the function instead of the name of object of ChildA class.

Comment: We can use this.GetType() function to get type of ChildA class, but when I use `this` keyword, it refers to parent class MyProjectBase object.

Comment: By using `frm.GetType();` I am getting correct type that is of `ChildA` child class but not getting its instance.

Comment: you already have the instance `this` using which you are calling `GetType()`

Comment: `frm` is the instance. Its `real` type (aka `dynamic` or `runtime` type) is `ChildA`, but its `static` (or `compile time`) type is `Form` - because it's the type of your variable `frm`.

Comment: Yes I know that `this` is instance. But I was confused about it. Never the less thanks for help.